# NAS rsync - delete files from destination which are not on source and are 1 week old

Tags: rsync, synology

I have hyperbackup running from source NAS to destination NAS with the below settings

1. Backup type - Rsync
2. Options - reserve backup file at destination
3. With this i have a backup method that results in a file/fodler structure in the 2nd NAS, withut the hyperbackup proprietary format or tools

I have the below cronjob on source NAS via task schedule which deletes files on the destination NAS which are not present in source NAS.

```
rsync -avh --delete /path/to/source user@wan_ip:/path/to/destination
```

I want to modify the cron job so that it deletes files from destination which are not present on source and 1 week old.
something like:

```
rsync -avh --delete(1 week old) /path/to/source user@wan_ip:/path/to/destination
```

Is there a way to do this?

The source and destination NAS both have multiple folders on which this Job has to run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any options for rsync that would do this per se, but you could try a two step approach.

You can add the `-b` parameter too your rsync call, which would cause it to rename the files with a backup extension instead of deleting them.
Then you could run a `find` afterwards that looks for backup files older than 1 week and deletes them.